# I need a way to break this loop or an alternative way to do this

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to js and firebase. I'm trying to use firebase database for a custom login by using my own table called users. I have used a for each loop to go through the data. But the else part is executed multiple time because of this. I need to break the loop so it won't happen.

This is my data:-

```
{"users" : [ {
    "userId" : "1",
    "username" : "admin",
    "password" : "admin",
    "type" : "admin"
  }, {
    "userId" : "2",
    "username" : "cashier",
    "password" : "cashier",
    "type" : "cashier"  
  }]
}**
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
var database=firebase.database();

function SignIn(){
var txtuser=document.getElementById('username').value;
var txtpass=document.getElementById('password').value;
var error=false;

firebase.database().ref('users').orderByKey().once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var users = childSnapshot.child('username').val();
    var pass=childSnapshot.child('password').val();

    if(txtuser==users && txtpass==pass){
      var type=childSnapshot.child('type').val();       
      if(type=="admin"){
        location.href="admin.html";
      }
      else if(type=="cashier"){
        location.href="cashier.html";
      }            
    }
    else{
      error=true;            
    }       
  });
});

if(error==true)
{
  window.alert("Invalid Credentials");
  location.href="index.html";
}
}
```

Comment: inside else part add condition if value is last value then only set error=true;

Answer (score 1):

### Password Authentication

Instead of using your method of storing authentication details in the database, use the [Sign in a user with an email address and password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) flow.

However, because you are using usernames not emails, append your storage bucket domain to the username (which will normally be `PROJECT_ID.appspot.com`).

So your `"admin"` and `"cashier"` users would become `"admin@PROJECT_ID.appspot.com"` and `"cashier@PROJECT_ID.appspot.com"`. For the sake of email authentication, these are valid email addresses, even though they don't have inboxes.

You can then use [firebase.auth()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) across your web app to manage your user's access control to pages like "admin.html" and "cashier.html".

**Note:** If you ever send out email to your users, make sure to omit emails that match `"*@PROJECT_ID.appspot.com"`

### Answering the question

**WARNING: Do not authenticate this way.** Please use above method.

- Passwords should **never** be stored in plain text
- **Passwords should never be stored in plain text**
- Users should **never** have access to another user's credentials in any database

For the sake of answering the question, you could use the following code:

```
var database=firebase.database();

function SignIn(){
    var txtuser=document.getElementById('username').value;
    var txtpass=document.getElementById('password').value;

    firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('username').equalTo(txtuser).once('value')
        .then(function(snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                throw "username not found";
            } else if (snapshot.numChildren() != 1) {
                throw "duplicate usernames";
            }

            // only one child at this point, so only called once
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                if (pass != childSnapshot.child('password').val()) {
                    throw "password mismatch";
                }

                var type=childSnapshot.child('type').val();
                if(type=="admin") {
                    location.href = "admin.html";
                } else if(type=="cashier") {
                    location.href = "cashier.html";
                } else {
                    throw "unknown user type";
                }
            })
        })
        .catch(function(error) { // catches any errors thrown by promises
            location.href = "index.html";
        });
}
```

In the above code, each `throw` is caught by the `Promise` returned by the Firebase query. You can read up on [Promises here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: thank you for your reply, I was able to do the email authentication process :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `error` is set to `true` inside the `.forEach` and use `return` to "break" out:

```js
var database=firebase.database();

function SignIn(){
  var txtuser=document.getElementById('username').value;
  var txtpass=document.getElementById('password').value;
  var error=false;

  firebase.database().ref('users').orderByKey().once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var users, pass;
      
      if (error) { return; } // <-- "break" the "loop"
      
      users = childSnapshot.child('username').val();
      pass = childSnapshot.child('password').val();
      if(txtuser == users && txtpass == pass){
        var type=childSnapshot.child('type').val();       
        if(type == "admin"){
          location.href="admin.html";
        }
        else if(type == "cashier"){
          location.href="cashier.html";
        }            
      } else {
        error = true;            
      }       
    });

    if(error) {
      window.alert("Invalid Credentials");
      location.href="index.html";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: In this answer, the `if(error)` line will be hit before the firebase query has even executed. It's also worth noting that [`DataSnapshot.forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#foreach) will stop iterating (break out) if you return `true` and will return `true` if cancelled this way. So you could use `var hasError = snapshot.forEach(...)` instead.

Comment: @samthecodingman Ooops, you are right! First thought you mean the `if (error) { return }` line :D Of course, the very last `if (error)` should be placed _inside_ the function passed to `then`! I'll update my answer.